# class with generic type variable List

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading about generic types. I'm able to understand that generic types can be used to specify the type of content  can be consumed by objects or collections to avoid runtime error and solve it while compile time only.

I want to know how can I create a generic class whose type variable(T = List) is List. For example in below example its String.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test<T> {

    T string;

    public Test(T in) {

        this.string = in;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Test<String> o = new Test<String>("Generic");


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You just created a generic class and created an object where T=String.

Comment: I think you are confusing constructors and methods.Do you intend to have a member called `string` as well as the member that is a `List<T>` ?
You should probably have one constructor that initialise both.
Why do you think assigning a value to `string` will magically create a `List` and give you access to it through `v`>

Comment: if you created this class, not as a generic but as one where all the `T` were replaced by `String`, would you expect your code to work?
If not consider that the compiler will effectively be replacing all the `T` in your class with `String`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how can I create a generic class whose type variable(T
>   = List) is List.

Specify the `List` as parameterized type.

To have a generic Test of `List<String>` do for example :

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
...
Test<List<String>> o = new Test<>(myList);
```

Comment: `Test<List<String>>` <- Shouldn't that be just `Test<String>` as a field and a constructor with `List<T>` are already defined? With your method `v` would end up beeing a `List<List<String>>`

Comment: I agree with you. I have answered "simply" to the question. After the OP requirement is not very clear.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, can you please explain with one example to understand what you are saying ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your list strictly to be a list of strings. Then simply declare your list as `List<String>`

Answer (score 1):

in this way obliges the developer to use a class that belongs to the Collection es (List, ArrayList, Vector, ...)

```
public class Test<T extends Collection>{ ... }
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class Test<E,T extends Collection<E>>{ ... }
```

Comment: Don't use raw types. Either make it `T extends Collection<?>`, or specify an additional type variable: `E, T extends Collection<E>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just déclare your T like an extends of List
Change this:

```
public class Test<T> {
```

to this

```
public class Test<T extends List> {
```

In this case, you will not be able to write this:

```
Test<String> o = new Test<String>();
```

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)